# how start activity after each expandable items clicked

Tags: android, android-activity, expandablelistview

I created an expandable list from [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview). and now I want to set onClickListener for each items and start an activity when an item clicked!
the problem is here: in `getChildView` of `MyExpandableListAdapter` i cant use `startActivity()` method. what should i do?

Comment: You can use **setOnChildClickListener()** and **setOnGroupClickListener()** to **detect the click event on child and group items respectively**. To **start Activity you need context instance of parent Activity within your adapter example context.startActivity or context.startActivityForResult**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with below code:

```
    ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exlistView);
    MyExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.groups)
    {
        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v= super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);

            ((LinearLayout) v).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //.....
                    startActivity(...);
                }
            });
            return v;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set `onclick` event for each `childItem` and `groupItem` like this:
by `groupPosition` and `childPosition` you can detect which item is clicked

```
listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            return false;
        }
    });

listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: if both not cal so something happen in your list item xml file. can you post your list group and child layout